# Checking a .txt file strings against file names in another folder, if present delete (Python3)

Tags: string, python-3.x, glob

I know where my issue is in my code, but still can't get around it.

The program only goes through it once as I understand it opens the file ones, iterates through it and does only the bottom word. But I tried to loop it with while loop, if statement, etc. so it opens the file each time but it fails to do so and says some error with path of the file and that it can't find it.

Here is the code:

```
import os, glob


def delete(ban):
    path = os.chdir("C:\\Users\\User\\Desktop\\checker\\clean\\") 
    for file in glob.glob("*" + ban + "*"):
        print(file)
        os.remove(file)

file = open("Banlist.txt")
for word in file:
    delete(word)
```

I want the word to be extracted from Banlist.txt then checked if it exists in any filename in the folder "clean" and if it does delete it, then move on until finished checking all the items AND only then move onto the next word in Banlist.txt but I am stuck with the program only doing last word everytime.

Comment: Please provide the exact error.

Comment: As @ABusyProgrammer kindly requested - also a) better not change the dir for every candidate action inside loop, b) not expect os.chdir to return anything, but it might raise an exception, and c) maybe not escape backslashes, but use the elegant os.path et al. methods for assembling a portable path